# Creating a semitransparent overlay for the entire site

Tags: css, overlay, opacity

I've attempted to create an overlay with a semi-transparent PNG over the entire of my page.

For some reason certain elements in my page are still appearing full colour and this only seems to be applying itself to the backgrounds?

```
#overlay{
background-image:url(../images/overlay.png);
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
z-index: 20;
}
```

See: [www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk)

Comment: This is because the elements are children of the `overlay`, the overlay shouldn't have any children and make sure that you put a z-index which is higher than any of the other element in the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your overlay div includes all the div's that should become 'below' that div. You should create a separate div with the following css to use it as an overlay:

```
#overlay {
background-image: url(../images/overlay.png);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
}
```

In that way this will basically be your html:

```
<body>
   <div id='wrapper'>
   </div>  
   <div id='footerwrapper'> 
   </div>
   <div id='overlay'>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done this and it seems to be working however it is not expanding the full height of the page despite having a height of 100%? Updated the link.

Comment: Add {top:0; left:0} for right positioning if there's total wrapper over the whole content.